# Change item Row color in gridview ?

Tags: java, android, gridview

hellow evreybody please can you help me to change the color of row in gridview 
in getView(),for example i try to change the backround by row 
forexample if position ==4  the 4 row will be in black . 
but when i scrool all row  changed  background.

Comment: post your adapter code

Comment: have you added else case as well?

Answer (score 0):

Your model classes of your gridItems for your adapter should have an attribute 'color' .

In your getView method - when the 'position' is 3,7,11...etc change the gridview layout color and use the setColor attribute of your item to set the color to that particular item.

Along with this at the start of your getView method you can check if item.getColor is set then change the gridview layout color else it should have the default color.

For getting the desired position you can use the formula if position = (4n-1) which will give you your desired color changing positions i.e. 3,7,11....